# Breeze seems to get old values (fetch from server) of my property on my entity when it is became null - possible bug

Tags: javascript, breeze

I use Breeze in my Durandal SPA project.

I have a list of elements in my search result page. Whenever user click on 1 element, I query the server to be sure the item is not locked by someone else. If this is the case, then I display a modal dialog to warn the user about who is currently locking the item.

It works pretty well with the 1st scenario below:

Scenario 1:

- t:   element E is not locked.
- t+1: element E is clicked in my search result page
- t+2: query the server to check for locking on this element (result: not locked)
- t+3: display the detail page for element E

Scenario 2:

- t:   element E is not locked.
- t+1: element E is clicked in my search result page
- t+2: query the server to check for locking on this element (result: locked by John)
- t+3: display the modal popup to warn the user that John locked the element
- t+4: John released the element E
- t+5: element E is clicked again in my search result page
- t+6: query the server to check for locking on this element (result: locked by Paul)
- t+7: display the modal popup to warn the user that Paul locked the element
- t+8: Paul released the element E

(so at this time nobody is locking the element --> LockedBy should be null)

- t+9: element E is clicked again in my search result page
- t+10: query the server to check for locking on this element (result: locked by Paul) <- 
  !!!!

As you can see the problem occurs in step 10 of second scenario. It seems that whenever 
the value is null (LockedBy) then breeze is still using old values for this property?!

Any idea?

Below is my code for querying the server with Breeze:

```
var getTransportById = function (transportId, transportObservable) {
    // Input: transportId: the id of the transport to retrieve
    // Output: transportObservable: an observable filled with the transport

    var query = entityQuery.from('Transports')
        .where('id', '==', transportId)
        .expand("Sender.City, Sender.City.Country, Receiver.City, Receiver.City.Country, Insurances, Client.City, Client.City.Country, LockedBy");

    query = query.using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer);

    return manager.executeQuery(query)
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

    function querySucceeded(data) {
        transportObservable(data.results[0]);
    }
};
```

Below is a substract of my model:

```
public class Transport
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TransportNumber { get; set; }
    public string Remark { get; set; }

    public int? LockedById { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LockedTime { get; set; }

    public virtual User LockedBy { get; set; }
}
```

PS: when analysing traffic data in my browser, it seems that Breeze did not send any data for navigation properties when it isnull. So in my scenario, values in client cache became incorrect since someone else (another user in another session) changed this data and my client cache has not been correctly refreshed because Breeze did not send my properties with null value. Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a theory. By default the JSON.Net serializer on a Breeze Web API controller **does not return nulls**.

When data arrive from a query, Breeze merges the received values into an existing entity ... property by property. Can you see the problem?  Follow me:

1. You query for Foo with id=1
2. The received JSON is **{id: 1, name: "Foo"}** and Breeze sets the corresponding properties of the materialized Foo entity
3. Something on the server changes the name to "Bar"; you requery
4. The received JSON is **{id: 1, name: "Bar"}**; the Foo entity is now {id:1, name: "Bar"}
5. Something on the server changes the name to **null**; you requery
6. The received JSON is **{id: 1}**  There is no value for the `name` property !!!
7. Breeze merges the values. But **there is no `name` value to merge** so of course `name` retains its previous value.
8. The Foo entity remains {id:1, name: "Bar"} while the server equivalent is {id:1, name: null}

The one workaround I can think of is to **[reconfigure the JsonFormatter to send null values](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller)**. Another approach is to **[write a custom JsonResultsAdapter](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-service-data-mapping)** for this specific use case ... one that detects missing properties (e.g., `name`) and adds them to the node, in this case with a null value.

This scenario leads me to **question the wisdom of our decision to suppress null values by default**. I will bring this up with the team.

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally I reconfigure the JsonFormatter to send null values.